# How to determine if a number is binary and has an even amount of zeros with only one regex?

Tags: java, regex, binary

I want a regex to determine if a number is binary and if it has an even amount of zeros in it.

For example, if we consider these 3 numbers:

- 10001010
- 00010010
- 45671892

I want the regex to match the following:

- 10001010 //Does NOT match because it has an uneven amount of zeros
- 00010010 //Does match because it has an even amount of zeros
- 45671892 //Does not match because it is not a binary number

The current solution is the following:

```
[1]*(0[1]*0[1]*)*
```

I tested it with https://regex101.com/ and it works for me.
The question is still online just to see if anyone can come up with a more efficient solution

I am thankful for every help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Something like : `^[1]*(0[1]*0[1]*)*$`

Comment: Thank you! It works just the way I wanted it!

Comment: You are welcome. For the next time, even if your attempts don't work, add them to your question so you don't get so many downvotes

Comment: Ok, I'll consider this in my next questions, thanks!

Comment: Your version worked for me. How about you post that as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: don't know if it is useful for someone else, but have added my suggestion as an answer as requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[1]*(0[1]*0[1]*)*$
```

which can be interpreted in the following way:

find any number of `1` followed by pairs of `00` with optional one or more `1`s in between.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Long#parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String,%20int)) to check if the given number string represents a binary number or not. If yes, you can get a stream out of the number string, filter for `0`, count the number of `0`s and check if the count is divisible by `2` or not to determine if it has odd or even number of `0`s.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "10001010", "00010010", "45671892" };

        for (String s : arr) {
            // Check if the number string is binary
            try {
                // Can validate up to 64 bits
                Long.parseLong(s, 2);
                if (s.chars().filter(c -> c == '0').count() % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(s + " represents a binary number and has an even number of 0s.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(s + " represents a binary number and has an odd number of 0s.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(s + " does not represent a binary number.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10001010 represents a binary number and has an odd number of 0s.
00010010 represents a binary number and has an even number of 0s.
45671892 does not represent a binary number.
```

Comment: You should take care that the strings are not too long otherwise you will get a NumberFormatException if the strings to parse doesn't fit in int type.

Comment: @Eritrean - You have mentioned a very important point. Just to increase the range, I've changed from `Integer.parseInt` to `Long.parseLong` and also put a note that it will work only up to 64 bits.

Comment: In case you missed it, the op specifically wanted a regex solution.

Comment: Personally, I see nothing wrong with providing alternative solutions and helpful information.  I did that yesterday and the moderator deleted my post.  Regarding the parse exception, perhaps BigInteger would be useful here.

Comment: @WJS - Thank you. Yes, it's an alternative solution.